# Install PhpStorm 2016.1 on linux missing bin/phpstorm.sh

Tags: phpstorm

I just downloaded the latest copy of the tar.gz file from the website and the installation instructions indicate the bin/phpstorm.sh needs to be ran, however it is missing.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try unpacking or downloading the archive again, it's there.

> **debian$ wget https://d1opms6zj7jotq.cloudfront.net/webide/PhpStorm-2016.1.tar.gz**
>       HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>       Length: 193063900 (184M) [binary/octet-stream]
>       Saved to: ‘PhpStorm-2016.1.tar.gz’
>
> **debian$ tar xzf PhpStorm-2016.1.tar.gz**
>
> **debian$ ls PhpStorm-145.258.2/bin/**
>       fsnotifier       inspect.sh              phpstorm64.vmoptions
>       fsnotifier64     libyjpagent-linux64.so  **phpstorm.sh**
>       fsnotifier-arm   libyjpagent-linux.so    phpstorm.vmoptions
>       idea.properties  log.xml                 webide.png

Comment: oddly enough it was a problem with unpacking. I checked the tar.gz file and there were several files missing.